# Setting content description for Bottom navigation bars tab android Talkback

Tags: android, kotlin, accessibility, talkback

I am working on accessibility, and currently I want to set content descriptions for the bottom navigation bars. We have checked but have not gotten the proper solution for the same. Is there any possibility that we can set the role's bottom navigation bar (Home,Call,Chat)? I was set on the title and content description. But it read first the content description and then the title. I wanted the Talk bar to read only content descriptions (like: You select Home, You select Call, or You select Chat). Also, I saw it the first time I clicked on Home. It read like: Home tab 1 of 3 in list 3 items. I don't want the in-list 3 items" . I tried the code below, but it did not work.

ViewCompat.setAccessibilityDelegate(menuActionView, object: AccessibilityDelegateCompat() {
override fun onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(
host: View,
info: AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat
) {
super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info)

```
        info.contentDescription = getString(R.string.action_call)
       info.addAction(
            AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.AccessibilityActionCompat(
                AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.ACTION_CLICK, ""
            )
        )
    }
}
```

})